# Are there services that offer to recover data from irreparably water-damaged iPhones?

Tags: iphone, data-recovery, damage

I have an iPhone 6 which took a dump in a river. Since then, it will not turn on and does not register when connected to a computer, i.e. it is dead for all intents and purposes.

Does anyone know of a company that offers to read the data directly from the iPhone's flash storage or if this is even feasible (considering that damage is likely with the logic board since exchanging first the battery, then the Lightning connector and plugging into external power did not allow booting the device)?

I am aware that such services may be very costly. I was just wondering if there is a market for this kind of problem at all.

Comment: This is totally a guess...   but I've got to think this isn't popular / needed for iPhones.   Since contacts, calendars, app data, etc are all backed up / stored via iCloud, none of this would need to be recovered from the device itself.   Photos are backed up as well, or stored in iCloud photos.   I can't think of anything on a device that wouldn't be recoverable in some other way (via backups).   Unless backups were never enabled...  that's another problem.    But in general, iPhones are great in that everything is backed up and easily recoverable by restoring to a new device.

Comment: Did you try Google first? [Kroll Ontrack - Mobile Device & Memory Card Recovery](http://www.krollontrack.com/data-recovery/data-recovery-services/mobile-device-recovery/)

Comment: Take it to a repair shop and make sure that it's irreparable. I've saved a few water-damaged iPhones, which the owners thought were irreparable, myself. And do not try to turn the iPhone on anymore; that's the worst thing that one can do to a water-damaged iPhone.

Comment: @Charlie74 It happened on vacation with poor or no reception for several weeks. No iCloud backups during the entire time and only about 15% of photos were uploaded to Photostream.

Comment: @user3439894 I did but found nothing that was iPhone-specific and had a reasonably well-designed, straightforward website. I can't help but think that services can't be too good if the website their offered on sucks.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 I did. Irreparable is what they told me.

Comment: @Casimir,  Regardless of what you think about their website, nonetheless  Kroll Ontrack is one of the industry leaders in data recovery.  If they can't recover something then it probably wasn't recoverable to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, contact any major data recovery company, ex Drive Savers.

http://www.drivesaversdatarecovery.com/devices-supported/apple-iphone-data-recovery/